# Need clarfication on Micro-partitioning, Clustering in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am new to Snowflake and I read a lot of links and I am still trying to figure out what is micro-partitioning? what is Clustering? and how do they are interrelated? also, what is micro-partitioning depth means? like clustering keys can we also define the keys or range for micro-partition?

I would be grateful if someone could able to explain these in layman's terms.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Documentation is pretty extensive on that [topic](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-clustering-keys.html). As additional help you could use webinars, if you have access to [Snowflake University](https://community.snowflake.com/s/snowflake-university) then search for "Snowflake Data Clustering - Sep 2020"

Comment: Hi Krishh, I believe this is a quite wide subject to explain in layman's terms unless you had specific questions on these topics? In addition to the official resources, I would recommend this quite comprehensive article on this subject: https://interworks.com/blog/2020/05/28/zero-to-snowflake-automated-clustering-in-snowflake/

Answer (score 0):

- All data in Snowflake lives in a micro-partitition.
- When you define clustering for a table, then data will be sorted by that criteria before being stored in micro-partitions.
- Clustering helps to limit how many micro-partitions should be visited. As in a dictionary, "these micro-partitions only hold rows where the value of column X starts with an 'a' or 'b'".
- Clustering is not needed when the natural order is enough - this especially when inserting new data every day, and then limiting queries by date range.

Read more:

- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-clustering-micropartitions.html